# How to install the Spring Batch Samples project. Maven issues

Tags: spring-batch, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I am investigating Spring-Batch for implementation into our shop.  I'm also less than expert in Maven.

But, I've downloaded the samples and imported them into a project.  I've keyed all the maven dependencies.  However, I'm left with 7 missing Artifacts:

Missing Artifact:

```
    org.vmware.sqlfire:sqlfireclient.jar:1.0.3
    org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:3.0.1.GA
    org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:4.1.9.FINAL
```

there are handful more but fix one probably fixes them all.  I'm probably just not understanding the instructions to install Spring Batch Samples project.  I've been throwing rocks at this for several days trying to find the jars it needs.  I've seen Maven grab and maintain all the necessary jars before in other projects.

A side-bar.  Is Spring Batch worth exploring?  Is it actively being used in the marketplace, or has something else replaced it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For building a sample projects these jars are not mandatory.
Please find a some spring batch project, http://java.dzone.com/news/spring-batch-hello-world-1

[How can I get started with Spring Batch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609793/how-can-i-get-started-with-spring-batch)

Comment: Thank you @Sajith.  I checked out the link, and that will work fine to get me started.